# Swift - Not seeing my custom view class called from another custom view class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Just trying to follow some youtube tutorials and learn about custom views. I am sure I am missing something very basic here. After reading here and the net for hours I am giving up.

I have a custom view that slides out. I am planning on filling it with different custom views as needed. The slideOutView displays fine. However, I am not able to see the other custom view called FlashCardView inside it. I am calling FlashCardView from SlideOutView.

Thanks for the help!

code for FlashCardView class:

```
import UIKit

protocol FlashCardViewDelegate: class {

}

class FlashCardView: UIView {

    weak var delegate: FlashCardViewDelegate?
    let questionLabel = UILabel()
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let dummyView = UIView()


    //MARK: Initialization

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

code for SlideOutView class:

```
import UIKit

class SlideOutView: UIView {

    let slideOutView = UIView()
    let menuBarLine = UIView()
    let menuBarView = UIView()
    let menuButton = UIButton()
    let backButton = UIButton()
    let flashCardView = FlashCardView()

    let ratio = DeviceSpecificValues()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func addView() {

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

            slideOutView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.bounds.height, width: window.bounds.width, height: window.bounds.height / 2)
            print("slideoutview frame is: \(slideOutView.frame)")
            slideOutView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            window.addSubview(slideOutView)

            menuBarView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: slideOutView.bounds.width, height: window.bounds.height / ratio.menuBarRatio)
            menuBarView.backgroundColor = GlobalValues.menuBarViewColor
            slideOutView.addSubview(menuBarView)

            menuBarLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: menuBarView.bounds.width, height: GlobalValues.menuBarLineWidth)
            menuBarLine.backgroundColor = GlobalValues.menuTextColor
            menuBarView.addSubview(menuBarLine)

            backButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: menuBarView.bounds.width * 0.1, height: menuBarView.bounds.height * 0.9)
            backButton.center.y = menuBarView.bounds.height / 2 + GlobalValues.menuBarLineWidth
            backButton.setTitle("<Back", for: .normal)
            backButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            backButton.setTitleColor(GlobalValues.menuTextColor, for: UIControlState())
            backButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
            menuBarView.addSubview(backButton)

            menuButton.frame = CGRect(x: menuBarView.bounds.width * 0.9, y: 0, width: menuBarView.bounds.width * 0.1, height: menuBarView.bounds.height * 0.9)
            menuButton.center.y = menuBarView.bounds.height / 2 + GlobalValues.menuBarLineWidth
            menuButton.setTitle("Menu", for: .normal)
            menuButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            menuButton.setTitleColor(GlobalValues.menuTextColor, for: UIControlState())
            menuButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
            menuBarView.addSubview(menuButton)
            addFlashCardView()
        }
    }

    func slideIn() {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {

            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

                self.slideOutView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.bounds.height, width: window.bounds.width, height: window.bounds.height / 2)
            }
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    func slideOut() {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {

            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

                self.slideOutView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.bounds.height / 2, width: window.bounds.width, height: window.bounds.height / 2)
            }
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    func addFlashCardView() {

        flashCardView.frame = slideOutView.frame
        slideOutView.addSubview(flashCardView)
    }
}
```

Comment: seeing your code from the `FlashCardView` class it seems you haven't given any frames to your flashcardview

Comment: I did. Scroll to the bottom in slideoutview class. There is a function called addFlashCardView(). I set the frame there to the frame of slideoutview... not sure if that is the right way though.

Comment: no I mean this `class FlashCardView: UIView {

    weak var delegate: FlashCardViewDelegate?
    let questionLabel = UILabel()
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let dummyView = UIView()`

Comment: you haven't set any frames for those views

Comment: Ohh that is true. I did not. Those were to be added to the base view.But shouldn't I still be able to see the base view anyways?

Comment: No you can't see them because firstly they don't have frame sizes, secondly added in the view itself.

Comment: You were right. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :). upvote my comments thanks haha